# Executing a .sh file with php

Tags: php, html, bash, shell

I have written a very simple Hello World script as a bash file and saved it on my desktop.

I want to execute this file when a Submit button is pressed.

The following script works fine and I see the Hello World on the firefox webbrowser:

```
   <?php

     echo shell_exec('sh /home/administrator/Desktop/Helloworld.sh');

    ?>
```

However the following script does not give me any result:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>

<body>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['Submit1'])) {

 echo shell_exec('sh /home/administrator/Desktop/Helloworld.sh');
  }

 ?>

<Input Type = "Submit" Name ="Submit1" Value = "Save Parameters">


</body>
</html>
```

Any idea why? I don't get any errors in my log file.

Comment: HTML inputs need to be part of a form: I don't see any form anywhere in your markup

Comment: Check with your host too. Often `shell_exec()` is not allowed to run due to security issues. Ah new comment, seems it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not posting anything, for that you'll need a form, i.e.:

**file.php**

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
if (isset($_POST['Submit1'])) {
 echo shell_exec('sh /home/administrator/Desktop/Helloworld.sh');
  }
 ?>
<form action="file.php" method="post">
<input Name= "Submit1" type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

---

Also, make sure the file `/home/administrator/Desktop/Helloworld.sh` is executable, i.e.:

```
chmod +x /home/administrator/Desktop/Helloworld.sh
```